# open authentication - how can I do this easy

Tags: asp.net, openid

I want to allow users to log in to my site using google, facebook, yahoo. Something like stackoverflow allows. My question is, How can I do this fast and easy? I am developing the website in asp.net. Is there any SDK or something that can allow me to implement a login system like this fast and easy?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321267/how-can-i-implement-most-login-open-id-in-my-website-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/  
or
http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: thanks, http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/ looks nice. Did you try any of them? Can any of this be integrated with Membership provider?

Comment: both are widely used, I tried the second one a long time ago but have no idea about integrating with Membership provider, the first one is banned in my country as the whole google code site is banned from google here .